# How to set returning type Observable?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular8

I have the following code:

```
  public check(data: ProjectSettings): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.post(this.checkProjectUrl, data);
  }
```

I get an error such:

> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type
>   'Observable'.   Type 'Object' is not assignable to type
>   'boolean'.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default HTTP methods in **`HttpClient`** returns an **`object`** as an **`Observable`**. You need to change type to **`boolean`** to return a **`boolean`** as an **`Observable`**.

```
  public check(data: ProjectSettings): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.post<boolean>(this.checkProjectUrl, data);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cast value by `post<T>`. In Angular docs you can find it as "Overload #8".

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post

```
public check(data: ProjectSettings): Observable<boolean> {
   return this.http.post<boolean>(this.checkProjectUrl, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public check(data: ProjectSettings): Observable<T> {
        return this.http.post<T>(this.checkProjectUrl, data);
      }
```

Comment: I dont want to use any, I need concrete returning type

Comment: Then cast it with `<T>`

Comment: Since we dont know what will return from the API you can type cast it with `<T>`. Udpated the answer accordingly